# NodeJS multiple topic listener for Firebase

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

I am trying to register listener for multiple nodes in the Firebase, currently, my mobile app is only listening to one node, and it is working fine, But i wanted it to listen to other topic/node too, how to achieve that?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

// imports firebase-functions module
// const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// imports firebase-admin module
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

/* Listens for new messages added to /messages/:pushId and sends a 
notification to subscribed users */
exports.pushNotification = 
functions.database.ref('/user_appointments/{userId}').onWrite( event => {
console.log('Push notification event triggered');
/* Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database */
    var valueObject = event.data.key;
    if (!event.data.exists()) {return}
    console.log(valueObject); 

/* Create a notification and data payload. They contain the notification 
information, and message to be sent respectively */ 
    const payload = {
        data: {
            title: String(valueObject),
            message: String(valueObject)
         }
    };
 /* Create an options object that contains the time to live for the 
notification and the priority. */
    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24 //24 hours
        };
      return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("user_appointments", payload, 
options);
     });
```

Comment: here you have more information : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the nodes have a similar structure, but are at a different location, you should separate the actual code into a helper function:

```
function sendNotification(event => {
console.log('Push notification event triggered');
/* Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database */
    var valueObject = event.data.key;
    if (!event.data.exists()) {return}
    console.log(valueObject); 

/* Create a notification and data payload. They contain the notification 
information, and message to be sent respectively */ 
    const payload = {
        data: {
            title: String(valueObject),
            message: String(valueObject)
         }
    };
 /* Create an options object that contains the time to live for the 
notification and the priority. */
    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24 //24 hours
        };
      return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("user_appointments", payload, 
options);
     });
```

You then tie this helper function to the two location in the database:

```
exports.pushNotification = 
functions.database.ref('/user_appointments/{userId}').onWrite( event => {
  sendNotification(event);
});
exports.pushNotification2 = 
functions.database.ref('/doctor_appointments/{doctorId}').onWrite( event => {
  sendNotification(event);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! its working, and i have accepted your answer.